# how to download file to disk using ajax and node

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

Ok so i am trying to do is to a save a file to the user's disk when they click on it. Here is code, ajax:

```
 $('.cv_download').on('click',function(){
        var fileName = $(this).text();
        console.log(fileName)
        var temp = {"file" : fileName}
        console.log(temp);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(temp))
        $.ajax({
            url: '/download-cv-file',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {fileSend:JSON.stringify(temp)},
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    })
```

in my server file i have:

`app.post('/download-cv-file', function(req, res){
    services.downloadFile(req,res);
});`

which fires :

```
var downloadFile = function(req,res){
console.log('From services')
console.log(req.body.fileSend)
var p_file = JSON.parse(req.body.fileSend);
console.log(p_file);
console.log('The file we look for is ' + p_file.file);
var file = 'services/cvs/'+p_file.file+'';
console.log('The file is ' + file);
res.download(file);}
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: it doesnt prompt me where do i want to save the file

Comment: there is no prompt in your code. does it write out anything to the console?

Comment: no , ican only see in the network that the request retruns 200 and finds the correct file with correct content-disposition and content-type. Maybe i am missing something ? I am still pretty new to this.

Comment: Maybe you can show an example for content deposition header? It should work. Which browsers where tested?

Comment: I tested in Chrome and Opera this is my Response Header
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:public, max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="CV.pdf"
Content-Length:155105
Content-Type:application/pdf
Date:Thu, 11 Dec 2014 15:16:02 GMT
ETag:W/"DXHclQFA2V7cXEn3QNak4A=="
Last-Modified:Thu, 11 Dec 2014 09:59:13 GMT
X-Powered-By:Express

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is sending the file with ajax. It will not work. You can use the following workarounds: Create an iframe with the file url or use the file api of html5.

Here is a good reference for this: [Download a file by jQuery.Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax)